# Java class doesn't see itself in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I ended up manually adding a java file "CreateGroovyScripts", to a local repo I had because the remote repo was not available. When I run it as a Junit, it gives me the following error:
[image: error]

Is there anything else I need to do with the project? It is a maven project and the only thing I have tried was to "Update Project" in the Maven sub-menu when I right click the project.

NOTE: The file was added using "New -> File" and then I simply named it CreateGroovyFiles.java and copy and pasted the code from a separate repo

Comment: To answer this question we would need to know a bit more about your project structure and the maven configuration you are using.

Can you add this information?

Comment: did you update the `package` declaration on the class

Comment: Right clic on project / Refresh... launch again

Comment: If you're using Maven, a `mvn clean` might do the trick

Comment: @jmw5598 how would I go about doing this? @J Mullen I would do this in cmd prompt in the same directory as the project, correct?

Comment: Try clean project and build the project. and meven clean as well.

Comment: Open `CreateGroovyFiles.java` and check the `package` declaration at the top and make sure it matches the file location `package com.<blacked out>inc.groovy;`

Comment: @jmw5598 oh right lol yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Remcoder what info would you specifically need for to know about the maven configuration? I have a settings.xml file that loads all dependencies when the project is built, but it did not load the CreateGroovyFiles.java when I initially cloned the remote repository, even though it was htere. Now the repo is not available for a bit and I had to "New -> File" add the CreateGroovyFiles.java and just copied the code from a different repo into that file and saved it

Comment: I did a Maven clean on the POM but is there a reason why the file in the pic has a question mark on it when the others don't?

Comment: I believe It has a question mark because Eclipse sees it as a new file which is not committed. Are you using GIT or SVN for versioning ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, when you run it as Junit , it does not work because the recently added class (i.e **CreateGroovyFiles**) is not in Eclipse project's **classpath**, and that might explain the ClassNotFoundException you get.

You can check whether it is in your build path or not by searching after it: 
Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and search after **CreateGroovyFiles**. If it does not find anything that means that the class is not
in the classpath.

In order to add it into the classpath you need to mark the folder containg all the depicted packages as a source folder.

Comment: I just tried this and it did find the class (has a green circle with "c" in it) . Thanks though! I didn't know to use that.